# Ubuntu 14.10 with linux kernel 3.15-rc8

Tags: 12.04

Please, where can I find:

Ubuntu 14.10 with Linux kernel 3.15-rc8 (ISO file)

kernel version to be 3.11 or higher

Thanks a lot.
Best Regards.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 release is scheduled for October 23, 2014.

Comment: please where can I find:
Ubuntu 64bits (ISO file)
kernel version to be 3.11 or higher

Comment: Can i for example donwload this http://www.ubuntu-fr.org/telechargement and do the upgrade http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/05/how-to-install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-3-14-4-in-linux.html   ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whats the packaged kernel version in Ubuntu 14.10, but if you don't find the iso with desired version then there is always and option to remaster the iso.

Comment: i want just any version of ubuntu kernel version to be 3.11 or higher, Have you an idea please ?